# Micro-ros reading operation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I

In Microros Client, It is the function rclc_executor_spin_some() that go check if there is data available in the (custom)transport? I don't understand which is the flow to arrive to the Micro-XRCE-DDS function uxr_run_session_<...> for read the message just arrived.

I miss the RCL part in the flow:

**RCLC**: rclc_executor_spin_some() --> **RCL**: .???.. --> **RMW**: run_xrce_session() --> **Micro-XRCE-DDS-Client**: uxr_run_session() and recv_msg()

In other word I would like to understand how MicroRos listen incoming message. ( And who? It s the executor?)

Thank you so much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387333/micro-ros-reading-operation/) by [Cccrri](https://answers.ros.org/users/83237/cccrri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved here: https://github.com/ros2/rclc/issues/200:

> `rclc_executor_spin_some` -> `rcl_wait` -> `rmw_wait` -> `uxr_run_session_until_data` and the former will call your transport read and write functions.
>
> In general the spin function in the executor is in charge of waiting for the middleware: in this step the middleware is ran and if there is any data it is stored in RMW layer static buffers. Then the executor performs a `rcl_take` that retrieves that data.
>
> Let me know if you have further questions.

---

Originally posted by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) with karma: 443 on 2021-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0